# In what way is the DGML graphic coordinate oriented?

Tags: visual-studio, dgml

**Context**

I am trying to convert a DGML graph into an SVG. I am using Javascript to read and parse the DGML **Nodes** and **Links** using Jquery. I created a DGML graph using Visual Studio 2017 (it has an interactive inbuilt editor). Essentially I need to create a mapping between the position of nodes on the DGML graph and a generated SVG. I have managed to make a conversion of every property of the nodes and links, except for a property called **Bounds**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectedGraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
<Nodes>
<Node Id="Node1" Background="#FF000000" Bounds="289.142857142857,-914.285714285714,56.9200000000001,25.96" Label="node 1" UseManualLocation="True" />
<Node Id="Node2" Bounds="-99.1466388157435,-813.468571428572,56.9200000000001,25.96" Label="node 2" UseManualLocation="True" />
<Node Id="Node3" Bounds="165.353095238095,-821.948571428572,56.9200000000001,25.96" Label="node 3" UseManualLocation="True" />
<Node Id="Node4" Bounds="231.884895804269,-672.637129778181,56.92,25.96" Label="node 4" UseManualLocation="True" />
<Node Id="Node5" Bounds="126.293653230212,-514.368957318116,56.9200000000001,25.96" Label="node 5" UseManualLocation="True" />
<Node Id="Node6" Bounds="513.21231765747,-699.551714460973,56.9200000000001,25.96" Label="node 6" UseManualLocation="True" />
</Nodes>
<Links>
<Link Source="Node1" Target="Node2" Bounds="-33.5154810441621,-893.916239433358,322.658338187019,83.7763765262094" />
<Link Source="Node1" Target="Node3" Bounds="218.428553771979,-888.325714285714,81.7729515442388,60.9960031621974" />
<Link Source="Node2" Target="Node4" Bounds="-42.8686314368827,-788.653915128306,267.113829712029,113.638782142621" />
<Link Source="Node2" Target="Node5" Bounds="-60.9032254171191,-787.508586425781,200.456326731834,265.952512098603" />
<Link Source="Node3" Target="Node4" Bounds="199.596870550233,-795.988597412109,51.3011424145167,115.130629087374" />
<Link Source="Node4" Target="Node5" Bounds="168.40836594804,-646.677165527344,83.2767077301747,124.821483021298" />
<Link Source="Node4" Target="Node6" Bounds="288.80489440918,-682.991837277453,215.448314485295,20.6119078319973" />
<Link Source="Node6" Target="Node1" Bounds="337.645038336076,-882.098554229514,190.482965266866,182.54683792092" />
</Links>
<Properties>
<Property Id="Background" Label="Background" Description="The background color" DataType="System.Windows.Media.Brush" />
<Property Id="Bounds" DataType="System.Windows.Rect" />
<Property Id="Label" Label="Label" Description="Displayable label of an Annotatable object" DataType="System.String" />
<Property Id="UseManualLocation" DataType="System.Boolean" />
</Properties>
</DirectedGraph>
```

[image: How the DGML looks like in Visual Studio]

I saw in the Property tag for "Bounds" the datatype is `System.Windows.Rect` which has a constructor `Rect(Double, Double, Double, Double)` 
- Initializes a new instance of the Rect structure that has the specified x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width, and height.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx

Since all the nodes have the same size, it is not wrong to assume that the final two parameters are width and height.

**Question**

How is the graphics coordinate system of the DGML oriented? For instance, an SVG graphic starts like most CG coordinates, left top corner origin; positive X towards right, positive Y towards bottom. I could not find any information on this on the DGML reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/directed-graph-markup-language-dgml-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your diagram i think the Y axis is inverted (top-down) and X axis is classical (left-right). Start of coordinates is between Node2 and Node5 somewhere behind the bottom of diagram view.

Answer (score 0):

My [DgmlPowerTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisLovett.DgmlPowerTools2017) provides a "Save as SVG" option under the "Share" toolbar item.